# Return list of Integers with SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to write a function that returns a list of Integers using SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery.
This is how i'm imagining it but doesn't work..

```
public List<Integer> queryInt(String sql, String[] whereArgs){
    //fetch string array
    List<Integer> r = new ArrayList<Integer> ();
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(
            sql,
            whereArgs
    );
    return c.toInt(); //something that does this
}
```

If someone has a clue, thanks for the help !

Answer (score 2):

You need to move within the Cursor before you can access any of the data (initially a Cursor will be positioned at before the first row (position -1)).

So your `queryInt` method could be :-

```
public List<Integer> queryInt(String sql, String[] whereArgs){
    //fetch string array
    List<Integer> r = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(
            sql,
            whereArgs
    );
    // Loop through the Cursor
    while(c.moveToNext()) {
        r.add(c.getInt(0)); //<<<< see note
    }
    c.close(); //<<<< Should always close a Cursor when done with it.
    return r;
}
```

- Note **0** assumes that the data is to be extracted from the first column. However it is considered better practice to not hard code the column offset but to get the column offset based upon the column name so `r.add(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(your_column_name_as_a_string)));` would be recommended.
- If there are no rows then the above would return an empty List, so you may need to check the returned List's size.

Comment: Thanks, regarding your note 0: how would you fetch the name of the column used in String sql?

Comment: Personally I would have all column and table names defined as constants (e.g. `public static final String COL_MYCOLUMN = "mycolumn";` as a class variable in say the DatabaseHelper class) and then use that e.g. `c.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_MYCOLUMN)`. Thus you define the column and tables names once and always refer to that throughout (even when building the sql string).